# What is the procedure to check the apache version in a sun solaris machine?

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

What is the procedure to check the apache version in a sun solaris machine?httpd -v is not working

Comment: Check the reply HTTP headers when connecting to a page on this server using `Live HTTP Headers` in Firefox (if you use Firefox). If your not using Firefox, just search for an HTTP Header Viewer on your browser of choice. As long as your server gives this information (which it should by default), you should see it in the header. Good Luck. Upvote this comment if it helped.

Comment: @HelpingHand: Instead of a comment, why not give an answer?

Comment: @Andrew Schulman Good idea! Just posted it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the reply HTTP headers when connecting to a page on this server using [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) in Firefox (if you use Firefox).

If your not using Firefox, just search for an HTTP Header Viewer on your browser of choice.

As long as your server gives this information (which it should by default in Apache), you should see it in the header. [This is the information that it COULD give you.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) Good Luck.

Accept this answer if it solved your problem. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

In what way does "httpd -v" not work? Does it return an error, or something else?

You may also be able to verify the version via the Solaris packaging system e.g. try "pkginfo" - if Apache has been installed as a package.

If you know exactly which httpd executable is running (e.g. "ps alxww | grep http") then you can determine which package owns that executable via "pkgchk -l -p /absolute/path/to/httpd"

But, in my experience, "httpd -v" should "just work" for the Apache httpd executable ...

Good luck.

Robb.

Comment: Most likely because httpd is installed in a directory not in the user path.   If the error is `httpd: Command not found.` (as I get on Solaris), run the command with the full path to the httpd binary, such as `/usr/apache2/2.2/bin/httpd -v` .